# How do I run Homebrew vi on macOS instead of the older version Apple provided?

Tags: command-line, macos

I have recently upgraded to Vim 8 using Homebrew, but my `vi` commands still load the OS-provided version 7.4 of Vim. I could add an alias to `vi`, but is there another way?

Comment: if you just want to go with vim 8, then you can simply remove vim 7.4 from your system. It will automatically solve your problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is happening because the OS's `vi` is ahead of Homebrew `vi` in the `PATH`.

While you could fix it by putting `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` in the `PATH`, that would be a security hole since Homebrew gives ownership of that directory to your user. That permission change from the macOS default means that even an extremely unsophisticated malware could use this hole to get root privileges. All they'd have to do is add some other common command here like `ls`, then pass the commands through to `/bin/ls` until they see you've run it through `sudo`, then they take over.

This is a general principle, not specific to Vi, Macs, or Homebrew at all: never place user-writeable `PATH` elements ahead of those that can only be modified by `root`.

There are several ways to solve this problem:

1. Replace the OS's `vi` and `vim` binaries with symlinks to the Homebrew versions:

   ```
   $ cd /bin
   $ sudo mv vi vi-7.4
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/vi .
   $ cd /usr/bin
   $ sudo mv vim vim-7.4
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/vim .
   ```

   I do not recommend this solution, but it is what the original version of the question asked for, so there it is.

   Notice that this doesn't delete the OS-provided versions, just renames them so you still have access to them by appending `-7.4` if you need to later.
2. Since all three of the directories in the prior solution are in the default user `PATH` on macOS, you don't actually need the symlinks unless you have local software that has hardcoded `/bin` or `/usr/bin` paths to `vi` or `vim`. Just move the system versions shadowing Homebrew's versions out of the way:

   ```
   $ sudo mv /bin/vi /bin/vi-7.4
   $ sudo mv /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim-7.4
   ```

   That causes `vi` and `vim` commands to fall through to the Homebrew versions in `/usr/local/bin`.
3. Both solutions above will break the next time you upgrade macOS because the OS installer will put the Apple-provided versions back in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, so the solution I actually recommend is to add aliases to your `~/.bashrc` file:

   ```
   alias vi=/usr/local/bin/vim
   alias vim=/usr/local/bin/vim
   ```

   This lets you switch back to the OS-provided version of Vim easily by quoting the alias:

   ```
   $ 'vi' somefile.txt         # forces use of /bin/vi
   ```

   You might also want to add this to `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   export EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/vim
   ```

   Several commands use `$EDITOR` instead of hard-coding a call to `vi`.
4. Another option you have is to remove the Homebrew build of Vim and install [MacVim](https://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/) instead. It also installs to `/usr/local/bin`, but unlike Homebrew Vim, it installs a command that isn't shadowed by the OS version, `mvim`. By default, that command launches the GUI MacVim editor, but with this alias, you can have your `vi` and your Terminal editor, too:

   ```
   alias vi='mvim -v'
   ```

   The `-v` flag tells it not to launch the GUI, but to edit in the Terminal instead.

   If you choose this option, make a similar change to the `EDITOR` definition.

   Among the many nice features you get with MacVim is integration with the OS clipboard: pasting from the OS clipboard into Terminal.app running stock or Homebrew Vim you already have, but I find it nice to go the other direction as well: "yank" commands in `mvim -v` under Terminal.app also sends the yanked text to the OS clipboard so I can paste it into some other program.

Comment: In response to the security concern, the responder here considers the security concern to be "bikeshedding": https://discourse.brew.sh/t/is-it-dangerous-to-have-usr-local-bin-ahead-of-usr-bin-in-your-path/6097

Comment: Note that methods 1 and 2 are difficult on recent macOS versions:  `mv: rename vi to vi-7: Operation not permitted`.  The alias in method 3 is still a good solution.

Answer (score 7):

Homebrew has an option `--with-override-system-vi` that can be used with `brew install vim` to do this.

Comment: `Error: invalid option: --with-override-system-vi`

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't have enough points to make a comment and i have seen `--with-override-system-vi` a ton of times I hope this helps someone else. Options were removed from brew - [github]: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/41128

I ended up switching to `neovim` https://neovim.io/

Steps if you want to do the same.

1. `brew install neovim`
2. In my `.zshrc` file I added `alias vim="nvim"`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This actually has quite some potential for an answer, especially if you mention the alternative ("If you want to override internal tools you'll have to put them in your path before the internal tools.") and particularly if you add details on how/what to add to `$PATH` to make this work! I'd definitely upvote such an updated answer.